# bigmap.get(key, "") with default param in case of no entry for key in the map with Taquito

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, storage, bigmap, taquito

Can we do something similar to `myMap.get(key, defaultValue = None)` of smartPy with Taquito?
An instruction like:

```
const myContract = await Tezos.contract.at(contractAddress);
const contractStorage = await myContract.storage();
const value = await contractStorage.myMap.get(key, defaultValue = 0)
```

Thnak you.

Answer (score 2):

As of Taquito release [v6.1.0-beta.0](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/releases/tag/6.1.0-beta.0) Taquito offers a new API for Maps which provides you with get and set calls.

The API does not offer an optional default value param, You will have to catch the error and assign your value.

We will change the behaviour of `get` to return undefined on the unknown key. I will update this issue when it is released. You can track Issue [298](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/298)